# Best approach of testing ravendb database queries speed

Tags: ravendb

Iv'e seached the internet for a while but am not able to find any examples how to test ravenDb query speed.

What I'm trying to achive is to compare two session.query and find out witch of those two has the best performance speed. How can I do that? //Thanks

EDIT:

I'm buliding a mvc Notes-app were a user can create an account and save notes. Lets say I have these these two classes:

```
public class SingleNote : ContentPage
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

And this one:

```
    public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Is it best to put a List of the users singleNotes in the LoginViewodel and store all the user notes there or should I put a property in the the SingleNote-ravenDocument that refers to the user.

What I'm then trying to achive is to test these to diffrent type of queris and se witch of them gets the best performace speed.

So, can I do some testing of that and compare these two queries witch gets best performance speed:

Case 1: where I have put the prop string UserThatOwnsTheDoc in SingleNote-class

```
`var listOfSpecificUsersDocuments =
        RavenSession.Query<SingleNote>()
                .Where(o => o.UserThatOwnsTheDoc == User.Identity.Name)
                .ToList();`
```

Case 2: where I have put the prop List SingleNotes in the LoginViewModel

```
var userDocumentWitchIncludesAListOfSingleNotes = RavenSession.Load<LoginViewModel>("UserName/1");
```

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for your response! I've now provided additional details. Hope that this new information is god enought to clarify my question// Thanks